# Undeleting entries (or restore previous version of deleted entry?)

Tags: entries, workflow

Is there a way to "undelete" an entry that has been deleted? (Kind of like the "Trash/Recycling Bin" functionality of our computer OS.)

I don't see any obvious way to do this, but since Craft Pro has page versioning it seems like perhaps there should be a way to restore an old version of a page that has since been removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

Craft added native [soft-delete support](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md#310---2019-01-15) to elements in Craft 3.1.

https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/soft-deletes.html

---

Currently not... Craft does a "hard" delete for its elements instead of a "soft" delete like what you're looking for.

You could probably pull off something close to what you're looking for with a plugin that listened to many of Craft's [onBeforeDelete*](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/events-reference) events, though.

Otherwise, sounds like a good feature request for the [feedback site](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com)!

Comment: I would also like to see a soft delete option in craft. I could not find a post about this on the feedback site, so i posted one: http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/9409188-soft-delete-entries

Comment: Since this is the officially accepted answer, it would be nice to have it updated to reflect the current reality (that craft soft deleted most entries), given that it is the first one people will see when viewing this post.

Comment: @AugustineCalvino done!

Answer (score 5):

In the toolbar above the element index you can use the "status" dropdown to filter by trashed elements. From there you can select the entries you want to recover and click the "Restore" button.

[image: Status dropdown]